# How can I use an Xbox 360 controller with a PlayStation 3?

Tags: xbox-360, ps3

My PS3 has basically gathered dust for half a year since I'm not feeling the controller. What are my most reasonable options for using a Xbox 360 controller on a PS3 (preferably wireless, but I have both wired and wireless)?

Comment: I dont think the thing can be done since both are competitiors in the gaming market. Maybe you could find some 3rd party PS controller that might do it for you?

Comment: @Fredy31: I've definitely seen it done (via Google search), but I don't know my options

Comment: There are adapters, but you may want to be careful with some games that require Sixaxxis (e.g. Uncharted) or the pressure sensitive face buttons (e.g. Metal Gear Solid 4), although I haven't seen a game, where either are absolutely necessary features.

Comment: I wouldn't add this as a new answer, but I can recommend you [this adapter](http://dx.com/p/xbox-360-controller-adapter-for-ps3-100cm-cable-51556), which works pretty good. I didn't have any major issues with it, plus it comes with a turbo adapter which makes certain quick time events easier (I'm looking at you, RE6). Keep in mind it won't support SIXAXIS.

Answer (score 7):

Based on my knowledge there are two solutions for your problem. To get things straight: The original Xbox-pads won't work out of the box with your PS3 and no solution will provide 100% of the features your dualshock-pads have (Sixaxxis, Trigger etc.).

**1. Use an Adapter**

There are some Adapters on the market (like the [XCM](http://www.xcm.cc/xcm_cross_battle_adapter_plus.htm) which Blem mentioned) which may be pretty pricy, but let you use your Xbox-pads on your PS3. The XCM does not allow you to use sixaxxis and I don't know any adapter which has this feature. Maybe someone who is using this (or another) adapter and can provide more precise information.

**2. Use an cheaper 3rd party gamepad**

A second way to play on your PS3 with an Xbox-like pad is to buy 3rd partie hardware which can be used on your PS3. I bought the [Speedlink XEOX](http://www.speedlink.com/?p=2&cat=4315&pid=25493&paus=1&act_lang=en&PHPSESSID=12502dd3d358905d9396b7ad22a312e8) pad, which can be used on the PC and the PS3. The Deadzones of the sticks are not as perfect as they are on the regular dualshocks, but you'll get used to it. Besides that the pad is wireless, so you don't have any wires through your livingroom (the XCM Adapter only works for the wired pad!). There is one little catch with the speedlink-pad with it's triggerbuttons:

> *Why can’t I operate the trigger buttons (R2 and L2) at the same time?*
>
> These two buttons’ signals are on the same axis. As such, they cancel each other out when both buttons are pressed at the same time. This gives you optimal control in many games. Alternatively, select the button assignment in the game so that both trigger buttons don’t need to be pressed at the same time.

Overall this specific pad is not as good as one of the original pads (Xbox / PS3), but is a good and cheap way to play with a Xbox-like pad on your PS3 (or PC).

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Not with the hardware that comes in the box. You'll have to get an adapter in order to connect the two. There are wired and wireless available out there.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using the XCM cross battle adapter.

As far as I can tell it supports wireless controllers if you also get the xbox pc adapter.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy an Xbox controller to PS3 adapter from many places.  I found one on ebay and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Xbox Controller on the Ps3 using the USB ports. The buttons are funky and sometimes they won't work. If you're playing a game like Call of Duty Black Ops 2, use the Lethal setup.