# Is it possible to use a xbox 360 controller with a PS4?

Tags: xbox-360, controllers, ps4

so my friend recently got Black Ops 3, and I've had a blast playing with him.

But, we usually 2 of our other friends also come over and we all try to play black ops 3 with each other, but we have to take turns.

I was wondering if there was any way I can maybe connect my xbox 360 controllers to his ps4 so we could all play black ops 3 split screen. Thanks.

Comment: Cross platform and cross gen, good luck with that; the same question was asked for ps3: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/122579/how-can-i-use-an-xbox-360-controller-with-a-playstation-3

Answer (score 3):

No. That is an xbox 360 controller for xbox which isn't compatible with playstation. You just have to save up money to get another dualshock 4.

Answer (score 1):

There are adapters you can get, I am almost 100% positive.

Like this one here:
http://cronusmax.com

Answer (score 0):

No, not possible. The controllers use different software and are incompatible.

Comment: can you mod an xbox 360 controller to think it's a ps4? Or is that impossible

Comment: Nope, if it was on a PC you could but consoles don't have the option. If buying a new controller isn't an option you could always buy a cheaper aftermarket controller instead.